# Given a table, how do I create a subset of all rows where given column matches a pattern, in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Given a table "foo", how can I select only those rows from "foo" where e.g. `foo$location like "%here%"`?

```
foo = data.table(location = c("here", "there", "here", "there", "where"), x = 1:5, y = 6:10)
foo
#   location x  y
# 1     here 1  6
# 2    there 2  7
# 3     here 3  8
# 4    there 4  9
# 5    where 5 10
# 6     nope 6 11
```

Desired result, "bar":

```
#   location x  y
# 1     here 1  6
# 2    there 2  7
# 3     here 3  8
# 4    there 4  9
# 5    where 5 10
```

Comment: Try `foo[location %like% "here"]`

Answer (score 0):

As it is a `data.table`, we can directly use the logical expression in `i` to subset the rows

```
foo[location %like% 'here']
```

-output

```
location x  y
1:     here 1  6
2:    there 2  7
3:     here 3  8
4:    there 4  9
5:    where 5 10
```

#### data

```
foo <- structure(list(location = c("here", "there", "here", "there", 
"where", "nope"), x = 1:6, y = 6:11), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R manner solution ([@akurn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67893196/12158757) is more `data.table` fashion, highly recommended)

```
> subset(foo,grepl("here",location))
   location x  y
1:     here 1  6
2:    there 2  7
3:     here 3  8
4:    there 4  9
5:    where 5 10
```